# Reading NfcA MifareClassic NFC Tags

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I have different Tags:

- an Amazon tag: NfcA
  http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00AESJ3B0/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00
- my key: NfcA
- some advertising tag: NfcA, Ndef, MifareUltraLight

I want to read out my key. The UID is `20 66 be 52`, the ATQA is `00 40` the SAK is `00 08` (ATQA and SAK is the same as from the Amazon key, so I guess it is also a Mifare Classic 1KB)

Whenever I try to `transceive(byte[])` I catch the `TagLostException`. Funny fact: advertising tag works better but still throws `IOException: Transceive failed`

Trying to parse the tag (for my key) to `IsoDep` or `MifareClassic` throws a `Nullpointer`. Only `NfcA` works but I can't read any data from the tag.

Can someone provide my valid commands or any other way to read the content from Android.

```
MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent);
mfc.connect(); //Nullpointer
```

**EDIT:** Seems like the problem could be my Nexus 4 (mainly bought it for NFC stuff :( ) it seems not to support MIFARE Classic Tags. But If you still have ideas write them down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it is clear now: Nexus 4 does not support MIFARE Classic (e.g. MIFARE Ultralight works)

It **can** read the UID, ATQA and SAK but it **can't** write nor read from the blocks / sectors.

Sad that a high end / flagship device like the Nexus 4 (and also the Nexus 10) is not able to read from the most popular tags.

Comment: Right. It doesn't support it not because it is not NFC Forum compliant, but because it uses a proprietary cryptographic algorithm (Crypto 1) that Broadcom and Google didn't want to license. On devices with NXP NFC controllers (Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, etc.) you get that for free, because the hardware supports it. Generally, you need to check the result `SomeNfcTech.get()` for null because not all are guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: Additionally the Crypto 1 algorithm is totally broken and there is really no excuse for using Classic for new projects.

Comment: I wouldn't pay license fees for a completely broken crypo as well. That Mifare Classic goes away is a good thing for NFC technology.

Comment: Would it theoretically be possible to reimplement Crypto 1 in software on an Android device (possibly by modifying the NFC software stack/driver, or does it have to be implemented on the NFC hardware?